# How to partialy hide a post until some link/button is clicked?

Tags: 7

I have some members on my site who do not follow the rules. What I would like to do to their posts is to hide them (may be using JavaScript) until a visitor clicks a `show link` or <kbd>button</kbd> with a warning message like:

> The source code of this post is not complete and not recommended for download, if you still want to download the source code, kindly click the show link/button to display the description of this post.

When the link/button is clicked, the description (body message) will then be shown.

Any suggestions about how to do this?

Comment: How do you differentiate these kinds of posts (which don't follow the rules) from posts that are OK (and do not have to be hidden)?

Comment: They submitted an incomplete source code like lacking the database file. Or they intentionally removed some forms or module from the project file.

Comment: @Clive What makes this post off-topic?

Comment: Did you read the message?